# R strsplit and filtering based on sub-indices matching in the logical vectors

Tags: r, strsplit

I want to apply strsplit in such a fashion that if there exist an identical pair of values with & (e.g. this is one pair with & `(NINA & SAM)`) and also with | (e.g. this is another pair but with | `(NINA | SAM)`) then keep the one with &

Below are 2 possible cases, and the length of these vectors (vec1, vec2) might vary among actual cases.

Case 1

```
> vec1
[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (PAUL | SAM) | (NINA & SAM) | (NINA | SAM) | (NINA & PAUL) | (NINA | PAUL))"
> vec2
[1] "((PAUL | SAM) & (PAUL & SAM) & (NINA | SAM) & (NINA | PAUL) & (NINA & PAUL) & (NINA & SAM))"
```

Case 2

```
> vec1
[1] "((PAUL | SAM) | (PAUL & SAM) | (!NINA & SAM) | (!NINA & PAUL))"
> vec2
[1] "((PAUL | SAM) & (PAUL & SAM) & (!NINA & SAM) & (!NINA & PAUL))"
```

This should be the outputs:

Case 1

```
> vec1
[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (NINA & SAM) | (NINA & PAUL))"
> vec2
[1] "((PAUL & SAM) & (NINA & PAUL) & (NINA & SAM))"
```

Case 2

```
> vec1
[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (!NINA & SAM) | (!NINA & PAUL))"
> vec2
[1] "((PAUL & SAM) & (!NINA & SAM) & (!NINA & PAUL))"
```

What I have tried so far:

My idea was to first remove the `((` and `))` from the start and end of the vector then split the vec1 on "`) | (`" and vec2 on "`) & (`" . Then further split the indices on `space*space` and check if sub index 1 and 2 matches with any other sub-index, if yes then keep the one which has `&`. Then put everything back together. I have a limited knowledge of R and I was unable to implement what I have in my mind. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following does what you want.
It is not very pretty but the outputs are correct.

```
keepAmpersand <- function(x) {
    y <- sub("\\(\\(", "(", x)  # get rid of the double
    y <- sub("\\)\\)", ")", y)  # parenthesis
    # this regex is meant to replace either a '|' or a '&'

    # with the same character between '#' (one '#' on each side)  
    y <- gsub("(\\) \\| \\(|\\) & \\()", ")#\\1#(", y)

    # now use that special pattern, '# five chars #' to split
    y <- unlist(strsplit(y, "#.{5}#"))

    # keep the ones with the ampersand or with just one name
    y <- grep("&|\\([[:alpha:]]+\\)", y, value = TRUE)
    y <- paste0("(", paste(y, collapse = " | "), ")")    # reassemble
    y
}
```

Now apply the function to each of the cases.

Case 1

```
vec1 <-
"((PAUL & SAM) | (PAUL | SAM) | (NINA & SAM) | (NINA | SAM) | (NINA & PAUL) | (NINA | PAUL))"
vec2 <-
"((PAUL | SAM) & (PAUL & SAM) & (NINA | SAM) & (NINA | PAUL) & (NINA & PAUL) & (NINA & SAM))"


keepAmpersand(vec1)
#[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (NINA & SAM) | (NINA & PAUL))"

keepAmpersand(vec2)
#[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (NINA & PAUL) | (NINA & SAM))"
```

Case 2

```
vec1 <-
"((PAUL | SAM) | (PAUL & SAM) | (!NINA & SAM) | (!NINA & PAUL))"
vec2 <- 
"((PAUL | SAM) & (PAUL & SAM) & (!NINA & SAM) & (!NINA & PAUL))"


keepAmpersand(vec1)
#[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (!NINA & SAM) | (!NINA & PAUL))"

keepAmpersand(vec2)
#[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (!NINA & SAM) | (!NINA & PAUL))"
```

Case 3: case when there is just one name between parenthesis.

```
vec3 <-
"((PAUL | SAM) & (PAUL & SAM) & (NINA | SAM) & (NINA | PAUL) & (NINA & PAUL) & (NINA))"

keepAmpersand(vec3)
#[1] "((PAUL & SAM) | (NINA & PAUL) | (NINA))"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking out the time to help me. The final output is missing the link in between the brackets, e.g. `"(PAUL & SAM)"   "(!NINA & SAM)"` should be  `"(PAUL & SAM)" |  "(!NINA & SAM)"` for the Case2 `vec1`. Secondly, the extra opening and closing brackets are also missing. Can you please comment the code so that I can easily understand what every line is doing. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Newbie See if this is it. Note that it is just `"(PAUL & SAM) | (!NINA & SAM)"` without the quotes near the bar `|`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just one little thing is that it is not working in the cases when parenthesis have only one name e.g. `"((PAUL | SAM) & (PAUL & SAM) & (NINA | SAM) & (NINA | PAUL) & (NINA & PAUL) & (NINA))"` In this case it will not report the last `(NINA)` . I am sorry I did not put such constraint in the input data sample, but actually I do have input like that.

Comment: I'm sorry if I am causing inconvenience fro you but in Case3 `(NINA | SAM)` is dropped out but originally it should not. As there is no other index which has these names. Can you please explain it. Thanks!